# Scala: Dynamic Dispatch

Tags: scala, dynamic-dispatch

Consider this Scala code:

```
class X {
    def m(a:A) = a.f(this) + ", " + "m(a:A) in X"
}

class Y extends X {
    override def m(a:A) = a.f(this) + ", " + "m(a:A) in Y"
}

class Z extends Y

class A {
    def f(x:X):String = "f(x:X) in A"
    def f(y:Y):String = "f(y:Y) in A"
}

class B extends A {
    override def f(x:X):String = "f(x:X) in B"
    def f(z:Z):String = "f(z:Z) in B"
    def g(x:X):String = super.f(x) + ", " + "g(x:X) in B"
    def h(y:Y):String = B.g(y) + ", " + "h(y:Y) in B"
}

object B {
    def f(x:X) = "f(x:X) in ObjB"
    def g(y:Y) = f(y) + ", " + "g(y:Y) in ObjB"
    def g(z:Z) = f(z) + ", " + "g(z:Z) in ObjB"
}

class C extends B {
    override def f(y:Y):String = "f(y:Y) in C"
    def h(z:Z):String = super.h(z) + ", " + "h(z:Z) in C"
    def k(x:X):String = x.m(this) + ", " + "k(x:X) in C"
}
```

The question given is: **Give the output of running the following program:**

```
val z: Z = new Z; val x: X = new Y
val c: C = new C; val a: A = new B
println(a.f(x)); println(a.f(z))
println(c.g(z)); println(c.h(z))
println(c.k(x))
```

I cannot seem to fully understand the output given. Here's what I think happens:

```
println(a.f(x)) = "f(x:X) in B"
println(a.f(z)) = "f(z:Z) in B"
println(c.g(z)) = "f(y:Y) in A, g(x:X) in B"
println(c.h(z)) = "f(y:Y) in A, g(y:Y) in ObjB, h(y:Y) in B, h(z:Z) in C"
println(c.k(x)) = "f(y:Y) in C, m(a:A) in Y, k(x:X) in C"
```

Yet, when I actually put the code into REPL, I get a different result:

```
println(a.f(x)) = "f(x:X) in B"
println(a.f(z)) = "f(y:Y) in A"
println(c.g(z)) = "f(x:X) in A, g(x:X) in B"
println(c.h(z)) = "f(x:X) in ObjB, g(y:Y) in ObjB, h(y:Y) in B, h(z:Z) in C"
println(c.k(x)) = "f(y:Y) in C, m(a:A) in Y, k(x:X) in C"
```

Why is this? I know that it is something to do with how overloaded methods are selected, but I could not find a single resource that precisely specifies how to determine which methods are selected, and when. If someone could explain the exact process, I would be grateful.

Comment: So the diff is only in `c.h`? There's no call to `A` anywhere in `h`.

Comment: @Reactormonk No, the differences are in `a.f(z)`, `c.g(z)`, and in `c.h(z)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with linearization as there is no multiple inheritance in the example. This example is about dispatch with methods [overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) and [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

First we need to separate "actual type" and "declared type". For examlpe in

```scala
val x: X = new Y
```

for variable `x` declare type is `X` and actual type is `Y`. You can't change actual type of a value but you can assign value of some actual type to variables of different declared types if they are super-types.

There is one simple (and a bit simplified) rule for call dispatch: for method overloading, which is dispatched first, i.e. when an object is passed as a parameter, its declared type is used to select the method; for method overriding i.e. when a method is called on an object, its actual type is used to select the method.

Additional rule `this` has always declared type of the class in which it is declared.

Also you should learn how to debug your applications. Debugging will easily show you which methods are called.

**Types**

In

```scala
val x: X = new Y
val z: Z = new Z; 
val a: A = new B
val c: C = new C;
```

- `x` has declared type of `X` and actual type `Y`
- `z` has both declared and actual types of `Z`
- `a` has declared type of `A` and actual type `B`
- `c` has both declared and actual types of `C`

Example #1 is trivial, so I'll omit it.

**#2**

```scala
println(a.f(z)) = "f(y:Y) in A"
```

Here we first need to resolve overloading i.e. find in type `A` method that accepts type closest to `Z`. It is

```scala
def f(y:Y):String = "f(y:Y) in A"
```

Now we need to dispatch overriding i.e. check if `B` overrides this method and the answer is no, there is no override for that method in `B` so output is generated by the method in `A`.

The reason why `B`'s

```scala
def f(z:Z):String = "f(z:Z) in B"
```

is not selected is that `a` has ***declared*** type of `A` and thus `B`'s more specific method is not visible in this context.

**#3**

```scala
println(c.g(z)) = "f(x:X) in A, g(x:X) in B"
```

Here we first need to resolve overloading i.e. find in type `C` method that accepts type closest to `Z`. It is `B`'s

```scala
def g(x:X):String = super.f(x) + ", " + "g(x:X) in B"
```

We can see that this method is not overridden in `C` so it will produce output. `super.f(x)` means `A.f(x)` since `B extends A`

**#4**

```scala
println(c.h(z)) = "f(x:X) in ObjB, g(y:Y) in ObjB, h(y:Y) in B, h(z:Z) in C"
```

Here we first need to resolve overloading i.e. find in type `C` method that accepts type closest to `Z`. It is `C`'s

```scala
def h(z:Z):String = super.h(z) + ", " + "h(z:Z) in C"
```

This give us last part of the answer. Now `super.h(z)` means `B`'s

```scala
def h(y:Y):String = B.g(y) + ", " + "h(y:Y) in B"
```

because there is no `h(Z)` in the `B` so we need to search for methods that accept base types of `Z`. This gives us second to the last part of the answer. Now `B.g(y)` is a call of `object B`'s

```scala
def g(y:Y) = f(y) + ", " + "g(y:Y) in ObjB"
```

This is so because in the context of `h(y:Y)` declared type is `Y` rather than original (and actual) `Z`. Obviously here `f(y)` is a call of `object B`'s

```scala
def f(x:X) = "f(x:X) in ObjB"
```

**#5**

```scala
println(c.k(x)) = "f(y:Y) in C, m(a:A) in Y, k(x:X) in C"
```

Again we first need to resolve overloading i.e. find in type `C` method that accepts type closest to `X`. It is `C`'s

```scala
def k(x:X):String = x.m(this) + ", " + "k(x:X) in C"
```

This gives us last part of the answer. Now resolve `x.m(this)`: we need to find in `X` method `m` that accepts type closest to `C`:

```scala
def m(a:A) = a.f(this) + ", " + "m(a:A) in X"
```

However this is the first time where  ***overriding*** steps in.  Actual type of `x` here is `Y` so the call will be to `Y`'s

```scala
override def m(a:A) = a.f(this) + ", " + "m(a:A) in Y"
```

Now we need to resolve `a.f(this)`. `this` here has a declared type of `Y` so

```scala
def f(y:Y):String = "f(y:Y) in A"
```

is a match in `A` but again this method is overridden in `C` so

```scala
override def f(y:Y):String = "f(y:Y) in C"
```

will be selected.

Comment: Thank you for a very fantastic and detailed answer. Let me clarify the context: this is a past exam question, and so I cannot debug the code. Nonetheless, this clarifies the concepts very well. So if, say, g(x:X) has been selected (just a general example), then any call from the function g will assume that x has type X, even if it has type Y? Thus, if g(x:X) calls f(x), it will match to f(x:X), not f(y:Y)?

Comment: @Jolyon, yes any call inside `g` that takes `x` as an argument will assume that type of `x` is `X` because this is the only safe thing to do for compiler. However, if you call some method on `x` **_and_** that method is overridden in `Y`, `Y`'s method will be called (if it is just declared in `Y` you will either get compilation error or less specific method in `X` will be called). P.S. One more thing, if you can write that code (and you surely did in the question), you can debug it yourself :)

Comment: Just looking back at your answer, and I believe you're wrong about the last part of the last question `println(c.k(x))`. You put it as `println(c.k(x)) = "f(y:Y) in A, m(a:A) in Y, k(x:X) in C"` whereas it should be `println(c.k(x)) = "f(y:Y) in C, m(a:A) in Y, k(x:X) in C"`, as even though it is called in `override def m(a:A) = a.f(this) + ", " + "m(a:A) in Y"`, the actual type of `a` in this context is `C`, and since there is an overriding method `f(y:Y)` in `C`, then `f(y:Y)` is called in `C`, not `A`.

Comment: @Jolyon, yes, you are right, last call is `f` in `C`. I'll fix the answer.